# 500 Internal Server Error,Request Timeout in nodejs resetpassword function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm new in Nodejs and ES6 .and I wrote codes for login and register and resetpassword.I've got this 
"This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout". when i try to call reset password in nodejs.I use es6 modules.How can i correct these code .

my code :

```
   export const resetPasswordInit=(req,res)=>{
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email},(err,user)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user){
        const random=randomstring.generate(12);
        user.tempPassword=bcrypt.hashSync(random,10);
        user.tempPasswordTime=new Date();
        user.save((err,user)=>{
            if (err)
            return res.status(400).send({
                message:err
            });
              const transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: 'mail.example.com',
                port: 465,
                secure: true, 
                  auth: {
                 user: "info@example.com",
                pass: "example12"
              }
             });

              const mailOptions={
                  from :'Sender Name <info@example.com>s',
                  to : req.body.email,
                  subject:'Reset Password Request',
                  html: `
                  <h1>Hi,</h1>
                  <h2>Here is your password reset key</h2>
                  <h2><code contenteditable="false" style="font-weight:200;font-size:1.5rem;padding:5px 10px; background: #EEEEEE; border:0">${random}</code></h4>

                  thanks,
                `
              };
                     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error){
          if(error){
          console.log('Error occured');
         console.log(error.message);
     return;
   }
  else
  {
 console.log('Message sent successfully!');
 }

 });
        })
    }
    else{
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'failed. No user found!'});
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You never respond to the request in the success case.

Comment: Tnx @jonrsharpe ,I corrected it, But doesn't work yet

Comment: You *haven't* corrected it, your code still doesn't always respond.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would you please tell me ,where is the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ,I think the problem is not because of respond ,it doesn't even send Email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never responded when everything went well i.e the success case. Try adding following line after sending mail i.e in the end of `transporter.sendMail` callback function.

```
res.status(200).json({
  message: 'Message sent successfully!'
});
```

Further please confirm that you are using valid smtp credentials and server address.

Comment: Hi ,you mean instead  of :   console.log('Message sent successfully!') ,I should write your code. But I still have the same error

Comment: try placing the code before `transporter.sendMail`.

Comment: check smtp credentials and server address too.

Comment: I've tried before,there is no problem in  Sending email